# Python f-string in jupyter notebook in loop not working

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-lab, f-string

I'm using python v3.8 with jupyter lab notebook, and I'm having problems with using f-string instead of regular print in a loop.
When I write in one cell

```
a=2
f" a={a}"\
f" a={a+1}+1 "
```

the output is
' a=2 a=3+1 ' (and without that 'back slash' character it would be just ' a=3+1 ', so I guess second f-string overwrites the first one here),
but in the case of the loop like

```
for i in range(11):
    f"{i}"
```

there is no output at all, while I want numbers to be printed like this

```
1
2
...
10
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: use `\n` as well or use `print (f"{i}")`

Comment: Your for loop misses the print statement around the f-string.

Comment: Use `print(...)` to print something. The only reason you get any output at all is because you're programming in a REPL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a print statement around the formatted string:

```
for i in range(11):
    print(f"{i}")
```

Comment: Right! I somehow decided that f-string can be used instead of print(), not as another formatting tool but as a substitution of print()... It was a long week :)

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with f-strings.

Without `print` functions, Jupyter notebooks only display the result of the last line in the cell:

[image: a cell with 3 lines without print and a cell with 3 lines with print]

When you use a backslash, it continues the line and Python considers it one longer line.  Multiple quoted strings are treated as one longer string:

[image: 3 quoted strings on one line, 3 quoted string on separate linse, 3 quoted strings with trailing backslashes on separate lines]

Comment: Right! I just forgot that in jupyter to get output I don't necessary need to call print() directly, that's why f".." was producing output by itself, but not in loop.